# I got errors running npm watch in Laravel 8 app with Midone - Vuejs 3 Admin Dashboard Template

Tags: laravel, vuejs3, inertiajs

Trying to install Midone - Vuejs 3 Admin Dashboard Template + HTML Version +
XD Design File ( HTML Version )
from https://themeforest.net/item/midone-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/28123408
in  new Laravel 8 / inertiajs/vuejs3 app / inertia-vue3 app

I read instructions how to install Midone under Laravel 8 /  app at
https://themeforest.net/item/midone-vuejs-admin-dashboard-template/28123408/comments?page=14

In the webpack.mix.js file mentioned line :

```
  .js("resources/app/main.js", "public/dist/js")
```

I do not have any resources/app/main.js  file, but I have resources/js/app.js with code:

```
require('./bootstrap');

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}.vue`),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .mixin({ methods: { route } })
            .mount(el);
    },
});

InertiaProgress.init({ color: '#4B5563' });
```

So I try in webpack.mix.js use this file :

```
const mix = require("laravel-mix");
const tailwindcss = require("tailwindcss");

const path = require('path'); //add this

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel applications. By default, we are compiling the CSS
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

mix.alias({
    "@": path.join(__dirname, "resources/app"),
    "~": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules"),
});

mix
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    // .js("resources/app/main.js", "public/dist/js")
    // .vue()
    .sass("resources/app/assets/sass/app.scss", "public/dist/css")
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js")],
    })
    .autoload({
        "cash-dom": ["cash"],
        "@popperjs/core": ["Popper"],
    })
    .browserSync({
        proxy: "midone-vue-laravel.test",
        files: ["resources/**/*.*"],
    });
```

1. I am not sure it correct way? The instructions above is a bit different I see in my new app.
2. I try to run npm watch, but I got a lot of errors :

   master@master-laptop:/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited$ npm run watch-poll

   > @ watch-poll /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited
   > mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000

   ✖ Mix
   Compiled with some errors in 2.77s

   ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/API/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/Pages/API/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 2:0-71
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/Pages/API/Partials/ApiTokenManager.vue' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/resources/js/Pages/API'

   ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/API/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/Pages/API/Index.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 3:0-48
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/Layouts/AppLayout.vue' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/resources/js/Pages/API'

   ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/API/Partials/ApiTokenManager.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/Pages/API/Partials/ApiTokenManager.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 2:0-61
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/Jetstream/ActionMessage.vue' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/resources/js/Pages/API/Partials'

   ...
   ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/Auth/ConfirmPassword.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/Pages/Auth/ConfirmPassword.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 3:0-71
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/Jetstream/AuthenticationCard.vue' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/resources/js/Pages/Auth'

   ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/Auth/ConfirmPassword.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/Pages/Auth/ConfirmPassword.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 4:0-79
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/Jetstream/AuthenticationCardLogo.vue' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/resources/js/Pages/Auth'

   ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/Auth/ConfirmPassword.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/Pages/Auth/ConfirmPassword.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js) 5:0-47
   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/Jetstream/Button.vue' in '/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/resources/js/Pages/Auth'

   ...
   ERROR in ./resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=317d1a6e&scoped=true&lang=css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-9.use[1]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/stylePostLoader.js!./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js??clonedRuleSet-9.use[2]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!./resources/js/Pages/Welcome.vue?vue&type=style&index=0&id=317d1a6e&scoped=true&lang=css)
   Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
   Error: Cannot find module '@left4code/tw-starter/dist/js/colors'
   Require stack:

   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/tailwind.config.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/lib/setupTrackingContext.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/tailwindcss/lib/index.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/webpack.mix.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
   - /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
     at Object. (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/tailwind.config.js:1:23)
     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)

     ERROR in ./resources/app/assets/sass/app.scss
     Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
     ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
     SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
     ╷
     13 │ @import "tailwind";
     │         ^^^^^^^^^^
     ╵
     resources/app/assets/sass/app.scss 13:9  root stylesheet
     at processResult (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:751:19)
     at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:853:5
     at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
     at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
     at context.callback (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
     at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7
     at Function.call$2 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:98996:16)
     at render_closure1.call$2 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:84511:12)
     at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:29540:18)
     at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:28062:21)

     1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
     webpack compiled with 101 errors

     ● Mix █████████████████████████ cache (99%)
     store build dependencies

     ### [Browsersync] Proxying: http://midone-vue-laravel.test
     [Browsersync] Access URLs:

     ### Local: http://localhost:3000
     External: http://213.109.234.130:3000

     ### UI: http://localhost:3001
     UI External: http://localhost:3001

     [Browsersync] Watching files...

I suppose that something is not configured properly?

What have I to fix ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 1:**

I modified path for alias in webpack.mix.js and added @left4code/tw-starter  package, but next running
npm run command I got error:

```
> @ watch-poll /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited
> mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000


✖ Mix
  Compiled with some errors in 3.55s


warn - The `purge`/`content` options have changed in Tailwind CSS v3.0.
warn - Update your configuration file to eliminate this warning.

● Mix █████████████████████████ done (99%)  
 plugins

ERROR in ./resources/app/assets/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
13 │ @import "tailwind";
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^
   ╵
  resources/app/assets/sass/app.scss 13:9  root stylesheet
    at processResult (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:751:19)
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:853:5
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:399:11
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:251:18
    at context.callback (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:124:13)
    at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/index.js:54:7
    at Function.call$2 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:98996:16)
    at render_closure1.call$2 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:84511:12)
    at _RootZone.runBinary$3$3 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:29540:18)
    at _FutureListener.handleError$1 (/mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/AdsMdnAdminarea/AdsMdnAdminarea_Inited/node_modules/sass/sass.dart.js:28062:21)
```

Yes I have in resources/app/assets/sass/app.scss at line 13:

```
@import "tailwind";
```

Also I have

```
"@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.4.0",
"@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.0",
 "tailwindcss": "^3.0.0",
```

packeges are  installed

I see warnings as for Tailwind in npm run command. How can I fix it? Did I miss some step ?

**MODIFIED BLOCK # 2:**
After in webpack.mix.js I modified line :

.sass("resources/app/sass/app.scss", "public/dist/css")

I got error :

```
ERROR in ./resources/app/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
69 │ @import "/left4code/tw-starter/dist/js/breakpoint";
   │         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Checking file resources/app/sass/app.scss I see line

```
@import "~@left4code/tw-starter/dist/scss/breakpoint";
```

and under /node_modules/@left4code/tw-starter I did not find any *breakpoint* files.

I commented line with breakpoint and got next error :

```
ERROR in ./resources/app/sass/app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
   ╷
63 │ @import "~@left4code/tw-starter/dist/js/accordion";
```

I found file /node_modules/@left4code/tw-starter/dist/js/accordion.js

As I have alias defined :

```
alias: {
    "@" : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'), // adjusted resources/app to resources/js
    "~": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
}
```

I tried to modify line in resources/app/sass/app.scss as :

```
@import "~left4code/tw-starter/dist/js/accordion";
```

but I got error that it was not found anyway...

I uploade a project from https://github.com/flydev-fr/midone_adminarea but got thesame errors trying to
run npm run watch-poll command...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I uploaded my project at
https://github.com/PetroGromovo/midone_adminarea
could, you please upload it and try to install ?

In the root there is archive midone-vuejs-admin-dashboard.zip - template itself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### Edited answer :

Some packages was missing and some other version mismatched. Please check the list for the principal issues *(you can check the commits on github)*:

- The views are in `resources/js`, not `resources/app`
- The `alias` config is wrong
- You need the package `@left4code/tw-starter` version **2.3.1**
- You have to downgrade **TailwindCSS v3** to **TailwindCSS v2**
- The `tailwind.config.js` needed to be configured for custom variables
- **PostCSS** need to be configured as well
- Images path needed to be fixed in css (using absolute path and placing the images in the public folder)

I have updated the repo.

#### Result

`yarn prod`

[image]

##### Original answer

The `alias` in your **webpack.mix.js** config is not working, that's why your are getting a lot of **imports errors**.

You just have to add to `webpack.mix.js` the following:

```
    .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            alias: {
              "@" : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'), // adjusted resources/app to resources/js
              "~": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
            }
        }
    })
```

Full config:

```
mix
    .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            alias: {
              "@" : path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js'), // adjusted resources/app to resources/js
              "~": path.join(__dirname, "node_modules")
            }
        }
    })
    .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    // .js("resources/app/main.js", "public/dist/js")
    // .vue()
    .sass("resources/app/sass/app.scss", "public/dist/css") // adjusted  resources/assets/app/sass/app.scss to resources/app/sass/app.scss
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false,
        postCss: [tailwindcss("./tailwind.config.js")],
    })
    .autoload({
        "cash-dom": ["cash"],
        "@popperjs/core": ["Popper"],
    })
    .browserSync({
        proxy: "midone-vue-laravel.test",
        files: ["resources/**/*.*"],
    });
```

You will eventually get an error when importing **tailwind** from your css, but to fix it, you need to install a missing package **@left4code/tw-starter** with `yarn add @left4code/tw-starter` and/or  ask to the seller directly support to use the latest version of his package which was updated 6 hours ago from this answer.

- fork: https://github.com/flydev-fr/midone_adminarea

Comment: Thanks! Please take a look MODIFIED BLOCK # 1

Comment: Why don't you use the scss file in `resources/app/sass` ?  Anyway, if you want to fix this, just copy the content from `resources/app/sass` into `resources/app/assets/sass`..

Comment: The github repo is also updated.

Comment: Thanks! Please take a look MODIFIED BLOCK # 2

Comment: @PetroGromovo as I said earlier, you are now at the point where you need to contact the author/seller of the template to ask support as the  package was updated. There is no `scss` extension file, they are renommed to `.css`. You can try to import them by replacing  each **@import css** directive, but will still encounter issues. Ask the author of the template where you bought it.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what have I to ask support of this plugin...

Now left4code/tw-starter has latest version Release 3.1.13  (Latest release    4 days ago )
Can decsion of this issue can be if I modify in package.json line
"@left4code/tw-starter": "^3.1.13"

some some prior versions that will fix this problem ?

To which version have I mo move ?

Comment: `midone` is a paid HTML Admin Dashboard Template made by the author Left4code which be brough on ThemeForest.  You have to ask support there with your license - what your asking to be fixed is not an opensource project.

Comment: @PetroGromovo check this link: https://themeforest.net/comments/27826902

Comment: Do you mean that a new update with TailwindCSS 3 support salve this issue?

Comment: Your comment made me realizing that using the right version of the package `@left4code/tw-starter` (speaking version 2.3.1) along the rest of the dependencies should fix things. I will update the answer and the repo after testing it.

Comment: The answer is updated and the repo as well. You can now use artisan to deploy your app.